# In angular how do i share data on a session basis

Tags: angularjs, session

So my understanding is that factories are singletons so any stateful data for a session would be ill placed here.

My next point of call was a service which returns a new instance of the service when injected however I am unsure how I would share one instance of the service to multiple controllers.

Is this an accepted way to solve this issue or does angular provide a better way?

My current use case is that I have a view with some partial views (each partial has it's own controller) and a modal window which takes in a row id and will display data dependant on that data.

I need to be able to share a instance of the service (or equivalent) across these controllers but on a per session basis.

How is this best done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The singleton exists for one user and loaded SPA. Thats what you would usually refer to as a session. Its a good place to store data that needs to be accessed by different controllers.

Comment: so are we saying that the singleton factory is not actually "app wide" but is in fact per user ? If so that makes things much clearer. Thanks

Comment: more precisely per session

Comment: "app wide" in the world of client side Javascript means per user.Dont get confused with a server side application wide state.

Comment: quite right, thanks; I have only recently started working on the client so hard not to think in server :)